# How to get desired button view using Bootstrap RTL?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I work on my Angular.js SPA project I use bootstrap3.3.7 version and and RTL Bootstrap Less in my projet.

I made import of RTL Bootstrap Less files to my bootstrap.css file:

```
 /*Core variables and mixins*/
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/variables.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/mixins.less";

/*Reset*/
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/normalize.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/print.less";

/*Core CSS*/
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/scaffolding.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/type.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/code.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/grid.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/tables.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/forms.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/buttons.less";

 /*Components*/
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/component-animations.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/glyphicons.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/dropdowns.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/button-groups.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/input-groups.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/navs.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/navbar.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/breadcrumbs.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/pagination.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/pager.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/labels.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/badges.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/jumbotron.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/thumbnails.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/alerts.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/progress-bars.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/media.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/list-group.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/panels.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/wells.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/close.less";

/*Components w/ JavaScript*/
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/modals.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/tooltip.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/popovers.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/carousel.less";

/*Utility classes*/
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/utilities.less";
@import "RTL-Bootstrap-Less/responsive-utilities.less";
```

So the style of the project is RTL.

Here some HTML code from my page:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="query" />
        <div class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the rendered view from code above:

[image]

The problem is with filter button it seems like inverted because the rounded corners are in the left side.

I want it to be like that:

[image]

It seem the problem because I use RTL style for my SPA project.

Any idea what do I have to change in my Bootstrap style configuration to get the desired view of the button?

Comment: Try the latest version of bootstrap RTL (3.4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your local CSS conflict with bootstrap otherwise it looks good, here is the fiddle code and output, see this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/21bab1pw/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="input-group">
          <div class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="query" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same look as in your link if I remove RTL bootstrap.But I need Bootstrap RTL because i use semitic languages in my project.